# Magento 2: Get WYSIWYG editor's data in frontend?

Tags: magento2, cms-block, wysiwyg, cms-pages

I add wysiwyng editor in admin Ui form.

```
<field name="content">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Content</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
            <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

It saves data in the following format in database, that' ok for me:

[image]

But when I get data in frontend, it shows this text instead of an image. 
I want to convert all `{{ }}` format to HTML like default CMS page, static block functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say the block that displays your content is called `Vendor\Module\Block\Entity`.
Add a dependency `Zend_Filter_Interface` to your block like this:

```
protected $templateProcessor;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcessor,
    .....
) {
    ....
    $this->templateProcessor = $templateProcessor;
    ....
}
```

Then create inside the block class a method like this:

```
public function filterOutputHtml($string) 
{
    return $this->templateProcessor->filter($string);
}
```

Then add this in your `di.xml` file:

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Block\Entity"> <!-- change name here to match your block class name -->
    <arguments>
        <argument name="templateProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Then in your template you can print the content like this:

```
<?php 
$content = $[entity]->getContent(); //$[entity] is the name of your class instance that comes from the db.
echo $block->filterOutputHtml($content);
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, It's working.....!

Comment: I have tried in another block it's shows "Cannot instantiate interface Zend_Filter_Interface" error

Comment: Make sure you add the same thing in `di.xml` for your new block.

Comment: Yes I forgot to define block in di.xml. it's working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: It is also possible to directly set the type of `$templateProcessor` to `\Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter` in the constructor and then you don't need to set the `di.xml` (not 100% the same thing, but it does the job).
Also don't forget to run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: This isn't working any longer in Magento2.4.6 when you run `s:d:c` `Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #8 [ <required> Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcessor ]` `In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:
                                                
  Class "Zend_Filter_Interface" does not exist` What would be the alternative I;ve heard Laminas but which file in laminas-filter anyone have an idea?

Comment: @JulianoVargas you can try to replace the zend filter interface with `Laminas\Filter\FilterInterface`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone looking for 2.4.6 Magento version this is the new replacement implementation class:

`use Zend\Filter\FilterInterface`