# Convert WYSIWYG content into html in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, wysiwyg

I want to get all content of WYSIWYG content display on my popup. When the WYSIWYG content has an image and text added then the image doesn't display.

I want to get output like that. If I added Bold effect on text and an image is added in the WYSIWYG content, then it will display output like bold font and the image is displayed. If I added just an image, then the image will be displayed in the popup. If I added just Bold effect on textm then it will displayed as bold text.

How can do like this?

Comment: I also found solution :
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
 echo $filterManager;

Comment: yes it's right but don't use object manager directly as Magento 2 standards.

Comment: Okey... @PrincePatel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say your popup has a block behind it to handle the logic, and a template to render the result (as it should have).
Let's say your block class is `\Vendor\Module\Block\Popup`

Add this to your block.

```
/**
 * @var \Zend_Filter_Interface
 */
protected $templateProcessor;
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcessor, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->templateProcessor = $templateProcessor;
    ....
}
```

Then create the method:

```
public function filterOutputHtml($string)
{
    return $this->templateProcessor->filter($string);
}
```

In your `di.xml` file add this:

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Block\Popup">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="templateProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now, in your template you can use this:

```
<?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($content);?>
```

where `$content` is the content you are trying to interpret as HTML.

Comment: Yes it's same answer which is given by you in my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/170554/35758 I will remove my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much bro :) works like a charm :P